# Google map in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I want to make web site like this.

http://sf.eater.com/maps/the-38-essential-san-francisco-restaurants-january-2015

I don't have any experience Google map API.
Where I can get sample code or theme like this?

Answer (score 0):

Google map api is pretty simple, but you need to use some other plugins as well to make it work like this website. Although i wont be able to handover the code to you, but here is what you have to do.

You just create a map and add points to a map and then add an event on the click. Take a look at this for a simple event. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple

You can replace the zoom in feature with windows load method to jump to a certain anchor on a page. You can also add any smooth scrolling plugin, You can use this code.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/.

Now when someone clicks on the map, javascript should be redirecting you to another page but because you will be using this technique with #anchors, instead of going to another page it will try to find this anochor on the same page. And the smooth scroll plugin will animate the scrolling for a better effect.